# Other than readability, is there any value add if I use += operator like x+=y instead of x=x+y in java

Tags: java, operators

I do understand that both **+=** and **var1=var1+var2** both do the same thing in Java. My question is, apart from better readability, what other benefit(if any) the former brings?  Im asking because I was curious why java developers introduced this, they should have done it because of some value addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x+=y` and `x=x+y` are not same.

`x+=y` is equivalent to `x=(Type of x)(x+y)`

```
byte x=4;
byte y=3;
x+=y; // x =(byte)(x+y)
x = x + y; // compile time error
```

Answer (score 10):

It prevents the LHS of the `+` operation from being evaluated twice.

```
var.getSomething().x = var.getSomething().x + y;
```

This is *not* equivalent to

```
var.getSomething().x += y;
```

However, the added value from increased readability and reduced typing effort is not to be underestimated.

Comment: This answer also is 100% correct, but the true value add I guess, is the answer provided by @Prince John Wesley. I could have accepted this answer also if I was allowed

Answer (score 0):

IMHO these operators (+=, -=, *=, /=) are inherited from C. In the old days (before we had highly optimising compilers), they could improve performance because on many architectures, these operators translated directly into a single assembler instruction. Nowadays, all compilers should automatically produce the same code. As for Java, I don't know if the client VM will produce the same bytecode even if there are no side effects on the RHS. Shouldn't make a difference in performance though.

And Dietrich is right, += et all prevent the argument from being evaluated twice (important when there are side effects).